# Finding the Function that Gives Investment Value as a Function of t

Tags: calculus

I have this question in a course review, and I can't wrap my ahead around it conceptually. Can anyone help and explain?

"When the interest on an investment is compounded continuously, the investment grows at a rate that is proportional to the amount in the account, so that if the amount present is P, then
dP/dt = kP
Where P is in dollars, t is in years, and k is a constant. If $180000

is invested (when t = 0) and the amount in the account after 17 years is $421,136
, find the function that gives the value of the investment as a function of t. (Round your value of k to two decimal places.)"

(a) P =

(b) What is the interest rate on this investment? (Round your answer to the nearest whole number.)

Comment: Are you able to solve the differential equation $dP/dt = kP$?

Answer (score 0):

The basic formula (from solving the differential equation) is cited per a source (see, for example, [discussion here](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/compound-interest/continuously-compounded-interest.php)) as:

> ${A_t = Pe^{rt}}$

where P is the starting investment (better perhaps expressed as, say, ${A_0}$), ${t}$ is the length of the investment period and ${r}$ is the continuous interest rate.

So, we must solve the following based on the inputs:

${421136 = 180000e^{r17}}$

or:

${421136/180000 = e^{17r}}$

Taking the natural logs:

${ln(421136/180000) = 17r}$

Dividing through by 17 implies a value of r = 0.049999, which rounded to the nearest whole percent is 5%.